# The virtual environment is made in my user s folder

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

No matter what folder am I'm, command 'pipenv shell' creat virtualenvironment named by my username, doesn't create virtualenvironment named by my project(folder's name). Could you please help me with that?

Comment: just to drew your attention, as of version 3.3, python is shipped with a native and builtin module `venv` to create a virtual environment, it's defacto module, the standard and the recommended way. to do so `python -m venv venv` and then `$ source <venv>/bin/activate` refer to https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: I solved erasing the pipfile.lock and pipfile from the folder s User. So I restart everything again and now all good :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I used "`pipenv shell`" to create a virtual environment on my computer. When it was originally in the global environment python3.8.3, it was named "`.venv`" by default:

[image]

It is recommended that you exit the original virtual environment before using "`pipenv shell`" to create a virtual environment. In addition, as 'cizario' said, we often use the command "`python -m venv .venv_name`" in VSCode to create a virtual environment and it can still be in this virtual environment automatically after refreshing the console:

[image]

Reference: [Virtual environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments).